# Reverse NuGet Lookup

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget, asp.net-core

Given an assembly I need, how do I find the NuGet package that provides it?

For example, I'm using ASP.NET Web API and I need the definition of `DelegatingHandler`.  In a painful manner, I determine that this is available in the NuGet package [`Microsoft.Net.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/).  But then, by accident, I discover it is [also available in the latest (4.0.0) version of `System.Net.Http`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31054070/284758).

There should be an easier way to locate the NuGet package or packages that provide the type rather than having a stumbling and guessing exercise with google.

Right now I also need the type `System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`, which is found in assembly `System.Net.Http.Formatting`. However, I'm not sure which NuGet provides it.  I should not need to guess, but I'm going to guess that the relevant package is `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`.  Unfortunately, that package lists `Microsoft.Net.Http` as a dependency, rather than the version 4.0.0 of `System.Net.Http` which I have chosen for my other Web API dependencies.

So I'm kinda stuck trying to figure out what NuGet package or packages to grab.

Is there a "Reverse NuGet Lookup" tool I'm overlooking that would simplify this search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the Reverse Package Search website but it includes only some of the NuGet packages, mostly those from BCL and ASP.NET: http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

In addition, if you are using Visual Studio with the latest tooling, you should be able type a type name and intellisense will tell you what package to add. For example, type `IApplicationRuntime`, press `ctrl + .` and you'll get a suggestion for `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions`.