# The current status of System.Net.Http vs. Microsoft.Net.Http

Tags: c#, nuget, httpclient, base-class-library

I am confused with packaging of `HttpClient`. Earlier it was distributed as a part of `Microsoft.Http.Net` NuGet package while `System.Net.Http` was considered legacy. Looks like now it's the opposite: there is a fresh `System.Net.Http` package for all platforms and `Microsoft.Net.Http` has not been updated in a while and according to folks at Microsoft development team is going to be deprecated.

Questions then:

- Can we replace dependencies on `Microsoft.Net.Http` NuGet package with (the newest) `System.Net.Http`?
- Should legacy .NET 4.0 platform still use `Microsoft.Net.Http`?
  What about non-Windows platforms (iOS, Android)? The new `System.Net.Http` supports them, but I remember with `Microsoft.Net.Http` I had to install additionally `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` and `Microsoft.Bcl` in order to get cross-platform stuff to work. `System.Net.Http` doesn't depend on them. Can Bcl packages be skipped?
- `System.Net.Http` lacks some Http extension methods, like `SupportsPreAuthenticate`, and an attempt to call these method results in runtime errors (missing method). How should we deal with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Net.Http vs Microsoft.Net.Http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053243/system-net-http-vs-microsoft-net-http)

Comment: Just to give a possible reason for the change: Network stack features differ a little bit between Windows platform and other OSes. I had troubles using a .NET application written for Windows in Mono environment for example. The change might indicate that finally it will be possible to be really platform independent, this could be why they move things to the System namespace. Look for references to this Http package from .NET Core, that might answer your question.

Comment: Looking at the packages downloaded from Microsoft.Net.Http nuget the only implementations of HttpClient are for net40, portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp71+wpa81, sl4-windowsphone71. For remaining platforms there are no implementations so I guess the System-one is picked?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has been for a long time and continues to be confusing.  I have seen such messaging myself but as of right now, it appears [System.Net.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.110).aspx) is the correct choice, at least for .NET on the Windows platform and has no external dependencies.

For .NET Core, I have used [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) although it does require [Microsoft.BCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/).  Unless you are experiencing problems, I suggest leaving legacy systems as-is, especially since these namespaces seem to be moving targets.

If that isn't confusing enough for you, the [HttpClient Sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=242550) linked from `System.Net.Http` uses [Windows.Web.Http](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http)!  That implementation is for Windows Store apps.

Perhaps next year this will all change again.

Comment: OMG .. can't we get a canonical answer from someone with authority ? :(

Comment: I'm using .NET6 . Could you please elaborately tell me the exactly what steps you took to make Microsoft.Net.Http package to get installed in a .NET6 -based solution? In Visual STudio 2022, I get the warning "Package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."