# StatusCodes class and HttpStatusCode enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Why there is [System.Net.HttpStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-7.0) class and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.statuscodes?view=aspnetcore-7.0) enum, when both of them seems to do the same?

Example:

```cs
public string Foo()
{
    int statusCode = StatusCodes.Status409Conflict
    // or
    int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict

    return $"There is a {statusCode} here."
}
```

Comment: System.Net.HttpStatusCode probably works with the System.Net.Http system, where AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes probably works with asp.net, a different framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpStatusCode` Enum is are inside the `system.Net` namespace, which means you can use it anywhere, especially when you need to read information from an API.

`StatusCodes` Class are inside the
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace

The next one is in use, the `StatusCodes` class gives you the codes as an `int` ,But in `HttpStatusCode` you have to cast them

Use them to position the code

Comment: Please format your answer better. Using backticks to encapsulate code and .Net keywords helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot add this as a comment since I don't have the rep, but I use `System.Net.HttpStatusCode` in my `Asp.Net Core 6` web app to check against a `HttpResponse.StatusCode`.

`System.Net` is present by default while `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` needs to be added as a dependency.

So use `System.Net` if you also have other services that depend on it (ex: `IPEndPoint`). No need to install a separate package.

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053243/system-net-http-vs-microsoft-net-http)

TLDR: This is all due to `Asp.Net Core`'s messy ecosystem